# Usage of objcopy / elfedit to patchelf symbol (versions) in elf file

Tags: shared-library, dynamic-linking, elf, linker, patchelf

The context is as follows: on my o.s. there is (already) *liba.so.v2* of  "liba" which contains the string 'symbol_version-2' as the symbol version for its functions , e.g. *functionX@version-2* (in my case, for ex. *wrefresh@NCURSES6_5.0.19991023*  in *objdump -T / readelf* output).
There is this new *binary_a* which I downloaded and want to run. This, however, has a dependency for a previous versions of the lib, *liba.so.v1*, which contains a different symbol version string, e.g. 'symbol_version-1'  (in my case *wrefresh@NCURSES_5.0.19991023* (notice the missing '6').

Notes:

- The functions (all of them) exist in both so libs and the new lib is **found** by ld.so (checked that using `LD_DEBUG=libs ldd ./binary_a` )
- The binary unfortunately doesn't have any reference to the 'new' symbol, otherwise, it would be easy to hexedit the binary , and adjust the *vna_flags* (see NewAppsOnOldGlibc link below)

My questions are :

1. **how to patch the binary such as to refer to the new symbol in the new lib** - using either dedicated Tools (objcopy / elfedit, others ...?), or even hexedit. For the  latter case I'd need please step-by-step advice on how to recalculate the hashes (if needed; according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21059674/17945815) it seems it's needed). There seems to be enough details in [dynTable-hash](https://flapenguin.me/elf-dt-hash) , however the information presented there is too complicated for me to make any practical use of for my use-case.
2. Why is *ld.so*  (still) complaining  that "it cannot find version", after I've hexedit out all references to the old lib.so and the old symbol ? *Is ld.so's cache somehow interferring ?*

All my attempts led to ldd (actually ld.so) complaining after patching the file, that it cannot find the new symbol version...

The ideal solution would avoid (re)compiling stuff (i.e. the *binary_a*) , except maybe compiling a 'dummy' function like in previous link, would avoid using LD_PRELOADs variables.

**What I've tried:**

- In my tests with *patchelf*, it produced a corrupt binary with flags *--remove-needed liba.so.v2* ; using *patchelf --replace-needed liba.so.v2  liba.so.v1* did rearrange the 'physical' layout of the file (as viewed with hexedit), but the symbols still referenced the v2 so lib, so I have doubts that this option worked as intended .To add more info: am hitting [this](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf/issues/214) with patchelf. The 'rearrangement' of the binary, seems it is referred to be *patchelf --debug*  when among other lines it says:
   `shifting new PT_LOAD segment by %d bytes to work around a Linux kernel bug`
- Testing with *elfsh* yielded another error, upon loading the binary,  don't have it in front of me know, but somthing like: *'elf header AMD64-x64 not recognized'*
- When 'hexediting' **another ** binary, where the symbol versions had the **same** string length (not like in this case, where there is a one char difference in the version string length) - so, an easier case - doing *ldd* on the resulted binary still complained that "symbol_version-2" not found. I would imagine adding a new entry ("symbol_version-2" ) in the *.dynstr* Table is not feasible (i.e. without decompiling the binary), is it ? If that would be doable, then I'd simply hexedit (overwrite) in the *vna_flags* field of  *Elfxx_Vernaux* entry corresponding to the 'old' symbol, to be the offset (in the .dynstr Table) of this new string, i.e. "symbol_version-2", again along the lines of [NewAppsOnOldGlibc](http://lightofdawn.org/wiki/wiki.cgi/-wiki/NewAppsOnOldGlibc)

Would following help - (a) changing the *soname* inside the lib.so.v2 file (using `patchelf --set-soname` or similar), (b) renaming the *lib.so.v2* file to *lib.so.v1*  and (c) fiddling with the version name (string) **only** ?
This would lead me again to asking: how would i trick *ld.so* into accepting my manual modification to the binary ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Isn’t the correct solution to install `libncurses5` instead of trying to patch the binary? Current `ncurses` ships both `libncurses5` and `libncurses6` packages, and not just for the fun of it.

Comment: This would be indeed the most strightforward solution, but in some cases there are external limitations imposed, e.g. each  new installed package needs to be audited first by whomever, or there is no internet egress connectivity , plus, sometimes a handful more :) 
Plus, I presume some software vendors simply link against whichever is the latest version of the dependency .so file, without any other real reason (not focusing here on security fixes which is a valid case).

Comment: Also,  installing an *older* version of a lib (which has probably more bugs  + security issues than a newer version) , just to satisfy a particular requirement of one older version - is relatively hard to describe as 'correct' solution.  
Also, if you could please provide more deep insight as to *why*  (aside the *"they're incompatible in some* way*") there are several versions of the given ncurses lib  (besides the 'not just for fun' reason) ,  it would be much more valueable than just stating the obvious I guess the, no offense - Thanks !

Comment: Ah, I thought you were interested in the general discussion rather than `ncurses` specifics ;-). For `ncurses` specifically, it’s not an older version of the library, it’s the same version built with an older API and ABI (notably, with different underlying types for some important data types). See https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ncurses/-/blob/master/debian/rules for details.

Comment: The underlying type difference in particular means that modifying a dependent binary to link to `libncurses6` instead of `libncurses5` is unlikely to produce a fully working result.

Comment: These last 2 comments of yours definitely shed more light on the issue (in the general way, as well as for this specific case/lib). So, I guess, am I safe to assume these discrepancies in the ABI versions stem*probably* from  being compiled by newer versions of the compiler ? 
Or what other reasons could account for this ABI incompatibility - let's presume the piece of code (e.g. the specific functions needed from this lib) is identical between the 2 versions of the lib ?
One reason might be changing f.e. *uint8_t*  instead of *unsigned char*. Any other reasons ? 
Thanks

Comment: The compiler doesn’t affect the ABI; there have been some cases in the past where G++ broke ABI on upgrades, but that was known in advance (and resulted in a ton of work in distributions). If a library changes its soname, that means that the ABI is changing in some way. That can be an innocuous change for many dependents, *e.g.* if a little-used function is removed (so a binary not using the old function could use the new library).

Comment: In other cases though it can be a significant but non-obvious change, *e.g* if API types change in a source-compatible way — so the API doesn’t change, but the ABI does. As a general rule, if a library changes its soname, it’s explicitly *because* it can no longer be used with existing binaries. That’s also why there aren’t any nice tools to do what you’re asking in your question.

Comment: Thank you,  have a [much] better understanding now