# Directly Replacing Text in Binary File

Tags: bash, sed, grep, binary

I have a compiled executable (binary) file - `mybin` - which `grep` indicates contains a positive match with a given text string - `Cats`.

```bash
grep "Cats" mybin
Binary file mybin matches
```

If I use the `-a` flag with `grep`, I can now see the actual match:

```bash
grep -a "File" mybin
<lots of text> (QString)Cats <lots of text>
```

Just to be clear, this is not a plain text string within the binary file i.e. I cannot see it if I open the file with a text editor.

What I want to do is replace occurrences of the string `Cats` within the binary file with the string `Bear` and keep the executable as a working executable.

How do I do this without changing it in the source code and recompiling the binary? Is such an operation even possible without corrupting the executable file and its operation?

If it is possible:

1. How would do I do it?
2. Are there any pitfalls I need to be aware of, for example the replacement string must be the same length as the original string (e.g. `Cats` -> `Bear` is ok but `Cats` -> `Dragons` is not).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mark, mind your quotes - the ones in the text are "smart quotes" and these will trigger errors (at best) if used at the shell prompt. Perhaps you meant to use ordinary quotes but your editor mangled them? In this case you will need to take care to repair the breakage

Comment: [CLI: Editing binary strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/450262/100397)

Comment: [Usage of objcopy / elfedit to patchelf symbol (versions) in elf file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/686677/100397)